# Equivalent definitions of $C^*$-systems.

Tags: operator-theory, dynamical-systems, operator-algebras, automorphism-group

I'm trying to compare the two following definitions of $C^*$-system trying to translate the one into the other.

Definition 1:

A $C^*-$dynamical system is a triple $(\mathfrak{A},G,\alpha)$ where $\mathfrak{A}$
is a $C^*$-algebra, $G$ a locally compact group, and $\alpha:G \rightarrow Aut(\mathfrak{A})$
a group homomorphism, which is assumed to be strongly continuous, i.e. for any $a \in \mathfrak{A}$ the map $g \mapsto \alpha(g)(a) \in \mathfrak{A}$ is norm continuous.

Definition 2:

A $C^*$-dynamical system is a pair $(\mathfrak{A},\Phi^t)$ $(t \in \mathbb{R})$ where $\mathfrak{A}$ is a unital $C^*-$algebra and $\Phi^t$ a one-parameter strongly continuous group of $*$-automorphisms of $\mathfrak{A}$.

In my understanding the second definition is given in order to encode the evolution of the system, so basically $G = (\mathbb{R},+)$ and therefore we are considering

\begin{align}
\Phi : \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow Aut(\mathfrak{A})\\
t &\longmapsto \Phi^t(a) \quad \forall a \in \mathfrak{A}
\end{align}

that is assumed continuous in the strong operator topology, that is, $\|\Phi_\alpha(a)-\Phi(a)\| \rightarrow 0$ for each $a \in \mathfrak{A}$.

Also, choosing $\mathbb{R}$ as $G$ I'm automatically saying that the group $\{\Phi^t\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ describes a REVERSIBLE dynamics? While choosing for example $\mathbb{N}$ means that my dynamics is dissipative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition 2 is just a special case of Definition 1, where $G=\mathbb R$.

As far as your last questions are concerned, I'm not familiar with what is meant by the terms *reversible* and *dissipative* in this context, but if reversible is to mean that every $\alpha(g)$ has an inverse of the form $\alpha(h)$, then every $C^*$-dynamical system described by definition 1 is reverisble, as $G$ is a group and $\alpha$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Yes in mathematical terms, one can think of reversible dynamics as the linear map $\Phi$ is invertible, while dissipative when is does not admit an inverse. If I assume to have $G = \mathbb{N}$ can I still say that the map is invertible?

Comment: Well $G=\mathbb N$ doesn't fit into either definition, as $\mathbb N$ (with any everyday operation) is not a group.  You can relax the group condition in definition 1, and just talk about (point-strong) continuous homomorphisms from a topological semigroup $G$ to $\operatorname{End}(A)$.  Then, in general, it will not be invertible.

Comment: Yes thank you, Now I got this. That's the reason why a 'dissipative' dynamics is described by the concept of Semigroup, where actually the notion of group is relaxed. So by relaxing the definition of the group, should I relax the arriving-space too? Basically I'm not talking about automorphisms anymore but endomorphisms instead.

Comment: Exactly.  Just change the requirement that $G$ is a (locally compact) group to $G$ is a (locally compact) semigroup, and change $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ to $\operatorname{End}(A)$ in definition 1.

Comment: Perfect..it all makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!